# How to use InputFormatter on Flutter TextField?

Tags: dart, flutter

What do I need to insert into `TextField(inputFormatters:`?

I want to disallow <kbd>\</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd> in one `TextField` and only allow <kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>Z</kbd> in another.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

### Formatters

In the [services library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/services-library.html) you will find the [`TextInputFormatter` abstract class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html) (this means that you have to import `package:flutter/services.dart`).

It already has implementations, which are [`FilteringTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html) (formerly `BlacklistingTextInputFormatter` and `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter`) and [`LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter-class.html).

If you want to implement your own formatter, you can do so by extending [`TextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html) itself and implementing [`formatEditUpdate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter/formatEditUpdate.html) in there.

I will show how to apply the premade [`FilteringTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html) with given context.

### Examples

> disallow <kbd>\</kbd> and <kbd>/</kbd>

For this we are going to use the [`FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny` constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter/FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny.html):

```dart
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'[/\\]')),
  ],
)
```

For the [`Pattern`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-core/Pattern-class.html), which needs to be supplied to the formatter, I will be using [`RegExp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html), i.e. regular expressions. You can find out more about that [here, which also links you to the features I will be using in my examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended:%7E:text=A%20bracket%20expression.%20Matches%20a%20single%20character%20that%20is%20contained%20within%20the%20brackets.).

**Pay attention to the double backslash `\\` and the raw string (`r''`) in this example**. This represents only a single backslash in reality. The reason for this is that backslashes are [escape keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in [`RegExp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html), so we need to use two backslashes if we want to match the `\` character. We would even need quadruple backslashes(`\\\\`) without the raw string (`r'…'`) because Dart also uses backslashes as escape keys. Using a raw string will ensure that Dart does not unescape characters.

---

If we were to block `a`, `b`, `F`, `!`, and `.`, we would also put it in a list `[…]` like this:

```dart
FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('[abF!.]'))
```

This translates to "*deny/blacklist all 'a', 'b', 'F', '!' and '.'*".

> only allow <kbd>a</kbd> to <kbd>Z</kbd>

This time we use the [`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow` constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter/FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow.html):

```dart
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]')),
  ],
)
```

For this, we are specifying two ranges of characters: `a-z` and `A-Z`, which will also accept all the characters (here all the letters) in-between those two specified. This will also work for `0-9` and you can append any character to that list, e.g. `a-zA-Z0-9!.` will also take `!` and `.` into account.

#### We can combine this

```dart
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z]')),
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('[abFeG]')),
  ],
)
```

This is only to show that `inputFormatters` takes a `List<InputFormatter>` and multiple formatters can be combined. In reality, you can solve this with one allow/whitelist and a regular expression, but this does work as well.

#### `digitsOnly`

There are also already included [*static properties* in the `FilteringTextInputFormatter` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html#static-properties): one of these is [`FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter/digitsOnly.html).
It will only accept/allow digits and is equivalent to an `.allow(RegExp('[0-9]'))` formatter.

Comment: I want this InputFormatters to be trigger when we call textCOntroller.text = "phonenumber" is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: U can also use '[a-z]/i' for case insensitive match, including A-Z

Answer (score 19):

Other options:

- lowercase letters : a-z
- capital letters : A-Z
- lowercase vowels accented : á-ú
- capital vowels accented : Á-Ú
- numbers : 0-9
- space : (a space)

*Note: the spacings are to explain better*

```
inputFormatters: [
        WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-z A-Z á-ú Á-Ú 0-9]"))
      ]
```

Comment: Thank! About 'space : (a space)', very simple

Answer (score 18):

`BlacklistingTextInputFormatter` and `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` is `@Deprecated` **version 1.20.0**

Now you can use `FilteringTextInputFormatter` to do `InputFormatter` on `TextField` or `TextFormField`.

```
    inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^ ?\d*')),]
    inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(' ')]
    inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly]
```

For e.x

```
  TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: [
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to check you have imported the following package:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

then you can use it like following:

```
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"), allow: true),
  ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Use these parameters in the `TextFormField`.

```dart
maxLength: 5,
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,],
```

Comment: While this answer may be correct. Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code and provide an explanation for how this code solves the problem.