# Restrict Special Character Input Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a TextField that will only take numbers as an input.
The Keyboard that appears allows for the input of the the following characters: "-(hyphen) ,(comma) .(period) and space". How can I prevent the user from entering all except the period.

```
child: new TextField(
  controller: _controller,
  maxLengthEnforced: true,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  maxLength: 4, //9999 upper limit
  ), //TextField
```

I've tried to use RegExp to take the _controller text, remove the characters and place it back into to field without any luck.

```
...//Add Listener to _controller
_controller.addListener(restrictCharacters);
...

//Listener
void restrictCharacters(){
  RegExp regexp = new RegExp(
    r"^|\-|\,|\ ",
    caseSensitive: false,
    multiLine: false,);
  String text = _controller.text;
  String chng = text.replaceaLL(regExp,"");
  _controller.text = chng;
}
```

When applied the cursor moves to beginning and the field keeps the - (hyphen) for example.

Answer (score 89):

In your TextInputField(), use a FilteringTextInputFormatter like this:

```
TextField(
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z]")),
  ], // Only numbers can be entered
),
```

Each character typed will be allowed only if it matches the RegExp.  To include a space, use the regular expression `"[0-9a-zA-Z ]"` instead.  Period means "any character" in regular expressions unless you escape them, like `"[0-9\.a-zA-Z]"`.

`.deny` can be used in place of `.allow` to proved a blacklist instead of a whitelist.

Comment: How can i whitelist spaces also?

Comment: By adding a space in the supplied regex, like this `"[a-zA-Z ]"`

Comment: WhitelistingTextInputFormatter has been deprecated. For anyone reading this comment, use FilteringTextInputFormatter.

Answer (score 21):

`WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` is deprecated. You should use `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow`:

```
inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]")), ]
```

or `FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny` instead of `BlacklistingTextInputFormatter`

Answer (score 13):

Add a `BlacklistingTextInputFormatter` to your `TextField`.

```
  inputFormatters: [
    new BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp('[\\.]')),
  ],
```

removes just `.` If you wanted to disallow, say, `.` and `,` change it to

```
  inputFormatters: [
    new BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp('[\\.|\\,]')),
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks
[TextInputFormatter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html)

    inputFormatters: [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp(r'[-]|[ ]|[,]'))],

Comment: It seems that this not work as intended.
[RegExp with multiple groups is not supported.](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/WhitelistingTextInputFormatter/whitelistedPattern.html)

Comment: This is incorrect, you don't need to escape with backslashes. It should be `[.,]`.

Comment: if you get here in 2024, `BlacklistingTextInputFormatter` does not longer exist. Instead use `FilteringTextInputFormatter` https://stackoverflow.com/a/50123743/7691350

Answer (score 8):

Add this to your  `TextField` for letters and numbers

```
inputFormatters: [new  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9]")),],
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want **double** to be added,you can also use the format like this:

`inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[0-9\.]")),],`

Be sure to include the backslash, as a period on its own means "any character" (allowing everything).

Answer (score 6):

**Dart 2.13+, Flutter 1.27+**

```
 inputFormatters:[FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9]'))]
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who need to work with money format in the text fields:

To use only: `,` *(comma)* and `.` *(period)*

and block the symbol: `-` *(hyphen, minus or dash)*

as well as the: `⌴` *(blank space)*

In your TextField, just set the following code:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
inputFormatters: [BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(new RegExp('[ -]'))],
```

The simbols *hyphen* and *space*  will still appear in the keyboard, but will become blocked.

Comment: The regex string could simply be `[ -]`. The escapes are unnecessary, and you're additionally blacklisting the pipe character `|` (which surely isn't an issue but still)

Comment: Right, you don't need the backslash escapes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I use. You can enter only numbers and only one dot. I think that this is the best solution for the number input field.

```
inputFormatters: [
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9.]')),
      SingleDotFormatter(),
],

class SingleDotFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
bool hasDot = true;
@override
TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
  TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
if (hasDot && newValue.text.endsWith('.') && newValue.text.split('.').length > 2) {
  return oldValue;
}

if (!hasDot && newValue.text.endsWith('.')) {
  hasDot = true;
  return newValue;
}

if (hasDot && !newValue.text.contains('.')) {
  hasDot = false;
  return newValue;
}

return newValue;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+|\s")),
  ],
  decoration: InputDecoration( 
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    hintText: 'Enter a search term',
  ),
),
```

1. FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow: This is an input formatter class provided by Flutter. It allows you to define a regular expression pattern to filter and restrict the input text. In your case, you are using a regular expression that matches alphanumeric characters (letters and digits) along with whitespace characters (\s).
2. RegExp(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+|\s"): This is the regular expression pattern that defines what text is allowed to be entered in the text field. Breaking it down:

- [a-zA-Z0-9]+: This part of the pattern matches one or more alphanumeric characters (letters or digits).
- |: This is the OR operator in regular expressions.
- \s: This part of the pattern matches whitespace characters, such as spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z]")),],
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to include English and Devanagari character also in your name
then follow this regex pattern
I have created this pattern for English letter and Devanagari letters with allow space

```
 inputFormatters: [ WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z \u0900-\u097F]")),
                    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(30),
                  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deny special characters with escape sequences
or get any escape sequence from google which you want

Example:

```
inputFormatters: [
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                      RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9\u0020-\u007E-\u0024-\u00A9]"),
                    ),
                    
                  ],
```

Comment: which part of this denies emojis?

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me, This is how to use FilteringTextInputFormatter inside TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter(
  RegExp("[a-zA-Z]"),
  allow: true),
  ],)
```

Set allow to false if you want to deny the RegExp.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `TextField` for letters and numbers

```
inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9]")),],
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import "services" package.

```
 import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Then you can use:

```
inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"^|\-|\,|\ "))]
```