# Limit TextField can input letter and spacing only

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I limit the `TextField` can only input letter and spacing?

I had try:

```dart
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    RegexFormatter(regex: '[A-Za-z]+'),
  ],
),
```

But it not work.

Comment: If you want to allow whitespace, shouldn't your regex also contain \s?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restrict Special Character Input Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442372/restrict-special-character-input-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the 2 works.

```
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
   FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
      RegExp(r"[a-zA-Z\s]"),
   )
]
```

or

```
inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
   FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
      RegExp(r"[a-zA-Z ]"),
   )
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
TextField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z ]")),
    // This will allow only characters and space
  ],
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
inputFormatters: [ FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-zA-Z]")), ]
```

For further understanding please refer
[Restrict Special Character Input Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50442372/restrict-special-character-input-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

Refer below code

```
 TextField(
        inputFormatters: [
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
            RegExp("[a-zA-Z0-9 ]"),
          ),
          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(10),//for limit of max length
        ],
       ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regexp

```
RegexFormatter(regex: '/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/'),
```