# Flutter undefined name WhitelistingTextInputFormatter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` in a `TextFormField` in a Flutter app but I get

> undefined name WhitelistingTextInputFormatter

Here is my code:

```
child: TextFormField(
         keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
         inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
         decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Staff Number', hintText: 'enter staff number'),
),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

can you confirm you are importing:

```
  import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

at the start of your file?

Also, i think here is the answer to your question:

[How to use InputFormatter on Flutter TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123742/how-to-use-inputformatter-on-flutter-textfield)

"In the services library you will find the TextInputFormatter abstract class (this means that you have to import package:flutter/services.dart)."

Answer (score 35):

Even though you have `package:flutter/services.dart` imported, in Flutter 2.8.0 was fully deprecated.
Please check the documentation:

```
@Deprecated(
  'Use FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly instead. '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.20.0-1.0.pre.',
)
```

Just change `WhitelistingTextInputFormatter` to `FilteringTextInputFormatter`

Answer (score 1):

First import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
Then Just change WhitelistingTextInputFormatter to FilteringTextInputFormatter.