# Allow Only lowercase with no space Input Textfield Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, lowercase

So i am making a chat app and i want user to submit username which should not be uppercase and have space, i can accept the name and change it later in onchanged feature but i want user to know it as well

Answer (score 10):

Flutter's `TextField` or `TextFormField` has attribute named `inputFormatters` which takes a list of `TextInputFormatter`.

an example of `TextInputFormatters` that is useful in your case.

`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-z]"))`

```dart
TextField(
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp("[a-z]")),
 ],
)
```

you can see `TextInputFormatters` API docs here : [Reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputFormatter-class.html)

---

(before flutter 1.20):

`WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-z]")),`

```dart
TextField(
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[a-z]")),
 ],
)
```

you can take those as reference if it's not clear enough : [Reference 2](https://dev.to/rubensdemelo/flutter-formatting-textfield-with-textinputformatter-1oii), [Reference 3](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-credit-card-text-formatter-1e259b28cfa3).

Also check out this SOF Question: [Reference 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123742/how-to-use-inputformatter-on-flutter-textfield)

Comment: Thank you very much @Saifallak, even if I searched for something total different.

But one hint:
'WhitelistingTextInputFormatter' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow instead. This feature was deprecated after v1.20.0-1.0.pre.

Comment: @Jakob Kühne , thanks for the correction, i will update my answer for future viewers!

Answer (score 1):

In regards to changing the text, try doing the following:

Let's say 's' is the username:

```
String s = ""
onChange(val) {
  s = val.trim().toLowerCase()
}
```

If you want to notify the user, perhaps use an alert dialog with some text letting them know the username should not be uppercase and contain no spaces. Regardless, you can't assume the user will conform to what they "should do".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Form` and then notify the user using the error field (Validator)

```
TextFormField(
                    validator: (name) {
                      Pattern pattern = r'^[a-z]+$'; // Regex for lowercase only
                      RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
                      if (!regex.hasMatch(name))
                        return 'Username must be lowercase, this will be changed when saved';
                      else
                        return null;
                    },
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text('Save'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _formKey.currentState.validate(); // just check if its valid and notify user
                      // Other code to save the and change the value
                      print('Saving Username');

                    },
                  )
```

[Dart Pad Example](https://dartpad.dev/b6409e10de32b280b8938aa75364fa7b)