# Flutter Disable type keyboard space , comma

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm beginner to flutter any one have some solution for the when im trying to type First Name , i wanna do disable typing keyboard space, comma , any idea how to do that?

I tried to used this formatter   `inputFormatters: [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp(r"[A-Z0-9]+"))],`

formatter not support
got a following error message

> WhitelistingTextInputFormatter' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.
> Use FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow instead. This feature was
> deprecated after v1.20.0-1.0.pre..

**code here**

```
 TextField(
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              controller: fNameController,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                isDense: true,
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14,top: 12,bottom: 12),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                ),
                                filled: true,
                                fillColor: Color(0xFFE1E8F7),
                                hintText: "",
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123742/how-to-use-inputformatter-on-flutter-textfield) answer your question

Comment: I got another solution for  v1.20.0  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825434/allow-only-lowercase-with-no-space-input-textfield-flutter

Comment: glad I could help