# Flutter: Is it possible to show a Message to User when TextFormField inputFormatter trims the text?

Tags: flutter

While the inputFormatters is realy well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123742/how-to-use-inputformatter-on-flutter-textfield) and works like a charm I want to let the user know about what happened to his input.
A simple snackBar or other dialog should be shown that prompts the user: "Your code has been trimmed because of unallowed signs. You are only allowed to enter numbers and letters!"

my example code shows the limitation to numbers and letters:
`TextFormField(                       inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[                         FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(                           RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z]"),                         ),                       ],`
If the user paste a string that contains other signs they will be deleted automaticly but the user might not see that so I want to show a warning to him.

I appriciate all help.

Comment: This article from the flutter team has what you need: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answeres but I solved it on my own as follows:

The inputFormatter blocks all unallowed signs and won't show them in onChanged value of the textController but the onChanged function is triggered and stays even. So I added the following code to the onChanged: function:

```
onChanged: (val) {
                    if (count == val.length) {
                      showSnackBar(
                        context,
                        'You entered an unallowed sign!', 
                        icon: Icons.warning_outlined, // this is from my own class showSnackBar which shows a Row with an optional Icon
                      );
                    }

                    count = val.length;
```

Everytime the user types an unallowed sign this warning pops up because the textcontroller changed but the value of it stays the same.

If there are parts I can do better please comment and I'll correct them.

The complete Code of the TextFormField including the inputFormatters:
First i created a variabel int count = 0;

```
TextFormField(
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                      RegExp("[0-9a-zA-Z]"),
                    ),
                  ],
                  obscureText: false,
                  controller: _controller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText:
                        'title',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    if (count == val.length) {
                      showSnackBar(
                        context,
                        'Unallowd sign typed in!',
                        icon: Icons.warning_outlined,
                      );
                    }
                    model.textChanged(val);

                    count = val.length;
                  },
                ),
```

Thanks